# The Nagel point revisited

Tags: geometry, synthetic-geometry

Let $i$ be the incenter of the triangle $\triangle abc$, and $n$ be the Nagel point
of this triangle (see [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagel_point) ).
Let also $h_3$ and $h_2$ be the orthocenters of the triangles $\triangle iab$ and $\triangle iac$,
respectively. Is it possible to prove with `GeometricScene` that the lines $an$ and $h_2h_3$
intersect on the inscribed circle of the triangle $\triangle abc$?

My first step is

```
RandomInstance[GeometricScene[{a, b, c, i}, {Triangle[{a, b, c}], 
Insphere[{a, b, c}], i == TriangleCenter[{a, b, c}, "Incenter"], 
Triangle[{i, a, b}], Triangle[{i, a, c}]}]]
```

which works well (Don't know how to insert a picture produced by the above code here.).

Comment: `RandomInstance[  GeometricScene[{a, b, c, i, h2, h3}, {Triangle[{a, b, c}],     Insphere[{a, b, c}], i == TriangleCenter[{a, b, c}, "Incenter"],     Triangle[{i, a, b}], Triangle[{i, a, c}],     h2 == TriangleCenter[{a, b, i}, "Orthocenter"],     h3 == TriangleCenter[{a, c, i}, "Orthocenter"]}]]` works too. It takes a long time.

Comment: 2.02 seconds is a long time?

Comment: My comp is not strong. `RandomInstance[
 GeometricScene[{a, b, c, i, h2, h3}, {Triangle[{a, b, c}], 
   Insphere[{a, b, c}], i == TriangleCenter[{a, b, c}, "Incenter"], 
   Triangle[{i, a, b}], Triangle[{i, a, c}], 
   h2 == TriangleCenter[{a, b, i}, "Orthocenter"], 
   h3 == TriangleCenter[{a, c, i}, "Orthocenter"], 
   InfiniteLine[{h2, h3}]}]]` also works.

Comment: Now that is slow - 26 seconds.

Comment: It takes several minutes for me.

Comment: @user64494 I took the liberty of running the code in the OP, exported the image and included that in the OP. I think it's a bit nicer now and hope you are ok with that. Can you please check that you agree with the image?

Comment: There is not iany `Insphere` in your picture. Please, insert a correct plot, In the other case your incorrect edit  will be deleted by me.  Deep regard.

Comment: @user64494 thanks for letting me know. that's odd. I tried it on version 12. will try to run the code on version 13 tomorrow.

Comment: @1729taxi I tried the code you said completes in 2 seconds and I aborted it after a minute or so without receiving a solution. Do you have a particularly powerful computer? Did you get the requested output from it?

Comment: @MarcoB - The timing varies on my machine from 1.2 seconds to about 6 seconds dependent upon the triangle generated. I'm on a MacBookPro at home. Output seems what is expected.